# Mechanics limiting speed with variable radius.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

Okay so I'm trying to solve this problem and have ran into some difficulties.

Using impulse change of momentum principles I managed to figure out that the equation of motion for the hailstone is

$$\displaystyle \frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{v}{m}\frac{dm}{dt}=g$$ however I don't know how to work out $\displaystyle \frac{dm}{dt}$ I thought it must have something to do with the differential equation given about the radius in the question but I couldn't figure it out and got stuck.

Presumably when I figure out $$\displaystyle \frac{dm}{dt}$$ I can just solve to find $\displaystyle v(t)$and take the limit as $\displaystyle t \rightarrow \infty$ and the answer should drop out.

Any help?

**QUESTION:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that you can solve the equation for the increase of the radius by $r(t) = r_0 e^{kt}$ where $r_0$ is some initial radius (this won't be important later on).  Assuming that the hailstone has a uniform mass density $\rho$ we can then give that

$$
m(t) \;\; =\;\; \rho \frac{4\pi}{3} r^3(t) \;\; =\;\; \rho\frac{4\pi}{3} r_0^3 e^{3kt}.
$$

Observe that

$$
\frac{dm}{dt} \;\; =\;\; \rho \frac{4\pi}{3} r_0^3 \frac{d}{dt}e^{3kt} \;\; =\;\; 3k \left (\rho  \frac{4\pi}{3} r_0^3 e^{3kt} \right ) \;\; =\;\; 3k m(t).
$$

Therefore the term

$$
\frac{v}{m} \frac{dm}{dt} \;\; =\;\; 3kv
$$

and the differential equation becomes

$$
\frac{dv}{dt} + 3kv \;\; =\;\; g.
$$

We can solve this using an integrating factor.  The rest should be straightforward from there.

Comment: Could you explain explicitly how you go from line 1 to line 2 of the equations? Also where does rho go on the first line second equals? Much appreciated thanks!

Comment: I forgot to include $\rho$ in the first line, so that was a typo.  In the second line, it should be straightforward to show that $\frac{dm}{dt} = 3k m(t)$.  Is that the part that is confusing you?

Comment: Surely $\frac{dm}{dt}=4\pi r_0^3e^{3kt}$ then the term is not what you say please help.

Comment: Yes that is confusing could you help me understand when I do it I get $\frac{dm}{dt}$ as above then multiplying by $\frac{v}{m}$ gives a horrible expression not a nice tidy one like $3kv$?

Comment: I augmented my solution above to show the computation.  Is it clearer now?  Instead of canceling out the 3's, it's better to express $\frac{d m}{dt}$ in terms of $m(t)$.

Comment: Got it you are a complete legend been looking at this problem for over 1 hour how do you get so good I'm jealous haaaa thanks bro!!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming spherical hailstones with density $\rho_h$, you can write the mass in terms of the radius as:
$$
m(t) = (\text{density})\times(\text{volume})=\frac{4}{3}\pi\rho_h r^3(t),
$$
so, differentiating both sides and using the chain rule you get that
$$
\frac{dm}{dt} = 4\pi\rho_h r^2(t)\frac{dr}{dt}=4\pi\rho_h k r^3(t) = 3km(t).
$$